# Volume of solid of revolution by shell method

Tags: calculus

consider the region bounded by $ \displaystyle y=4{{x}^{2}}$ and $ \displaystyle 2x+y=6$. What is the volume of solid of revolution about $\displaystyle x$-axis.

What is thought about setting the integral:

I split the region into two parts

$\displaystyle V=4\pi \int\limits_{0}^{4}{y\left( 1-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2} \right)\,dy}+2\pi \int\limits_{4}^{9}{y\left( \frac{6-y}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2} \right)\,dy}$

Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need to split the region. Notice that $y = 4x^2$ and $y = 6 - 2x$ both intercept at: $$4x^2 = 6-2x \implies2x^2 + x - 3 =0 \implies x = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+24}}{4} \implies x = \frac{-1\pm 5}{4},$$ so $x = -3/2$ and $x = 1$. Since the area of revolution of $y = f(x)$ around the $x$ axis is $$A = \pi \int_{a}^b f(x)^2 \ {\rm d}x$$ and $6 - 2x > 4x^2$ in $(-3/2, 1)$, the area you're looking for is: $$A = \pi\int_{-3/2}^1 (6-2x)^2 \ {\rm d}x - \pi \int_{-3/2}^1 (4x^2)^2 \ {\rm d}x.$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply.what happens when we try to solve it by cylindrical shell method?

Comment: Usually the shell method is used for revolutions around the $y$-axis, not the $x-$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the plot for $y = 4x^2$, and $y=6-2x:$

[image]

There is absolutely no need to separate $\mathfrak{R}$ into two regions. Find the intersection of the two curves and use $r = r_{out} - r_{in}$. Recall that

$$
\mathfrak{R} = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \pi r^2 \ dr.
$$

where $x_0$ is the leftmost intersection and $x_1$ is the rightmost.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.what happens when we try to solve it by cylindrical shell method?

Comment: Life gets a lot harder ;)

Comment: Suppose we insist to solve it by cylindrical shell method,I worked something like this after putting extra effort:

Comment: $\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^{4}{y\left[ \frac{\sqrt{y}}{2}-\left( -\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2} \right) \right]}\,\,dy+\int\limits_{4}^{9}{y\left[ \frac{6-y}{2}-\left( -\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2} \right) \right]}\,\,dy$

Comment: That's correct. You can verify it by evaluating the integrals and seeing that the quantity remains the same.